# how to get first fragment with supportfragmentmanager with findfragmentbytag

Tags: android, android-fragments, tabs

I am using a viewpager and a tabspageradapter. In my main activity I have an attribut to safe the current fragment in selected tab: current_tab. It changes its value when a new tab is selected, but i dont know how to set its value in the beginning because i need the attribut to update my listview in the fragments. I tried many things but i am gettings nullpointerexception most of the times, can anyone tell me how it would work?

Code of my TabsPagerAdapter:

```
public class TabsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

public TabsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm){
    super(fm);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int index){
    switch(index) {
        case 0:
            return new AllShowsFragment();
        case 1:
            return new UnwatchedShowsFragment();
        case 2:
            return new WatchedShowsFragment();
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 3;
}
}
```

Code of the most important parts of the Main Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
    ActionBar.TabListener {

public static FragmentCommunicater fragmentCommunicater;
public static boolean simple_progress;
public static int editmode;
private ViewPager viewPager;
private TabsPagerAdapter mAdapter;
private ActionBar actionBar;
private DatabaseHandler db;
private Show current_show;
private static MyFragment current_tab;
private boolean first_launch=true;

private String[] tabs = { "All Shows", "Unwatched", "Watched" };

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    db = new DatabaseHandler(this);
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    actionBar = getActionBar();
    mAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    for (String tab_name : tabs){
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tab_name)
                .setTabListener(this));
    }

    viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
        }
    });
}

public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    getSettings();
}

public void getSettings() {
    SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    simple_progress = sharedPrefs.getBoolean("simple_progress_key", false);
}

@Override
public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
}

@Override
public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
    Fragment page = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("android:switcher:" + R.id.pager + ":" + viewPager.getCurrentItem());
    if ((viewPager.getCurrentItem() == 0 || viewPager.getCurrentItem() == 1 || viewPager.getCurrentItem() == 2) && (page != null)) {
        current_tab = ((MyFragment) page);
        current_tab.update();
    }
}

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
}

public static void update(){
    current_tab.update();
}
}
```

Ony of my fragment classes where i get the new nullpointer exception:

```
public class AllShowsFragment extends MyFragment {
private SQLiteDatabase newDB;
private ListView lv;
private List<Show> showList = new ArrayList<Show>();
private int position;
private DatabaseHandler db;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_shows, container, false);
    lv = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.mainlist);
    lv.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                                       int pos, long id) {
            position = pos;
            createClickMenu();
            return true;
        }
    });
    return rootView;
}

public void update(){
    populateListfromDB();
}

public void populateListfromDB() {
    db = new DatabaseHandler(this.getActivity()); 
    newDB = db.getWritableDatabase(); //Exception at this line
    showList.clear();

    Cursor cursor = newDB.rawQuery("SELECT id as _id, title, cseason, cepisode, watched FROM "
            + db.TABLE_SHOWS, null);

    cursor.moveToFirst();

    if (cursor != null & cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        do {
            Show show = new Show(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)), cursor.getString(1),
                    cursor.getString(2), cursor.getString(3),
                    Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(4)));
            showList.add(show);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    myCursorAdapter = new CustomAdapter(this, showList,((MainActivity)this.getActivity()).editmode,
            ((MainActivity)this.getActivity()).simple_progress);
    lv.setAdapter(myCursorAdapter);
}
}
```

Exception, first few lines:

```
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:224)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:164)
        at wrodarczyk.com.showtracker.AllShowsFragment.populateListfromDB(AllShowsFragment.java:55)
        at wrodarczyk.com.showtracker.AllShowsFragment.update(AllShowsFragment.java:50)
        at wrodarczyk.com.showtracker.MainActivity.update(MainActivity.java:183)
        at wrodarczyk.com.showtracker.MainActivity.onTabSelected(MainActivity.java:134)
        at com.android.internal.app.ActionBarImpl.selectTab(ActionBarImpl.java:577)
        at com.android.internal.app.ActionBarImpl.addTab(ActionBarImpl.java:506)
        at com.android.internal.app.ActionBarImpl.addTab(ActionBarImpl.java:492)
        at wrodarczyk.com.showtracker.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:53)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have a small, fixed number of pages in a ViewPager, you can simply maintain your own pre-populated list of references:

```
public TabsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm){
    super(fm);
    myTabs.add(new AllShowsFragment());
    myTabs.add(new UnWatchedShowsFragment());
    // ...
}
```

Given this, your `getItem()` method will just return an indexed element from this array list.

Once you have your own index of tab fragments, you can store `current_tab` in an `int`, and your update call is something like

```
mAdapter.myTabs.get(current_tab).update();
```

Comment: thanks, that helped me a lot, but now i am getting a nullpointer exception im my fragment class, i edited the post with the new fragment code, would be nice if you have a look at it

Comment: You're welcome. A StackOverflow question should focus on one issue. When that one issue is resolved you should accept the best answer and if you have another issue, post a new question.

Comment: ok sorry for that, i will post a new question, thanks again for the help!